# Query to retrieve only the row with the biggest ID

Tags: sql, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to write a query to return only the row where the PeriodID is the BIGGEST for each of the documentID, such as:

```
Table1: DOCUMENT
DocumentID  ItemName
-------------------------
1           Doc1
1           Doc1    
1           Doc1
2           Doc2
3           Doc3

Table2: DOC_PERIOD
PeriodID    StartDate   EndDate    DocumentID
----------------------------------------------------
20          1/1/2001    2/2/2002    1
30          2/1/2001    2/3/2012    1   
40          3/2/2012    8/5/2012    1   
25          3/2/2012    8/5/2012    2   
35          3/2/2012    8/5/2012    2   
45          3/2/2012    8/5/2012    3   

EXPECTED OUTPUT
DocumentID  ItemName    PeriodID    StartDate   EndDate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           Doc1        40          3/2/2012    8/5/2012        
2           Doc2        35          3/2/2012    8/5/2012        
3           Doc3        45          3/2/2012    8/5/2012        


SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT
INNER JOIN DOC_PERIOD ON DOCUMENT.DocumentID = DOC_PERIOD.DocumentID
-- SCRIPT TO GET THE MAX PERIODID HERE
```

How should my query looks like ?

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify what RDBMS you using but if your database supports it you can use [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the result:

```
select DocumentId,
    ItemName,
    PeriodId,
    StartDate,
    EndDate
from
(
    select d.DocumentId,
        d.ItemName,
        dp.PeriodId,
        dp.StartDate,
        dp.EndDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by d.documentid order by dp.periodid desc) rn
    from dbo.document d
    inner join dbo.doc_period dp
        on d.DocumentId = dp.DocumentId
) src
where rn = 1
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, they didn't even specify whether it was SQL Server in the first place, although SQL Server is easier to assume than Sybase.

Comment: @AndriyM You are correct, I am making that assumption based on the `tsql` tag. I have updated my answer to remove the SQL Server comment. :)

Comment: Tag says tsql so it's SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Below Query... It will help you...

```
SELECT ts.DocumentID,ts.ItemName,ts.PeriodID,tp.StartDate,tp.EndDate 
FROM
(SELECT DOCUMENT.DocumentID ,DOCUMENT.ItemName ,MAX(PeriodID) PeriodID 
FROM DOCUMENT
INNER JOIN 
DOC_PERIOD ON 
DOCUMENT.DocumentID = DOC_PERIOD.DocumentID
group by DOCUMENT.DocumentID ,DOCUMENT.ItemName) ts

INNER JOIN

(SELECT DocumentID, Periodid,StartDate,EndDate from DOC_PERIOD) tp

ON ts.periodId = tp.periodID
```